# Gnome annoying shortcut keys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, shortcuts

Gnome have a lot of system-wide keyboard shortcuts that have conflict withs application-wide keyboard shortcuts.

Windows avoids such conflicts by using a dedicated key (super/window/OS key).
For example in Ubuntu <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> has a conflict with "move up line" in phpStorm. (Linux shortcuts have precedence to application-wide key, and I can not disable some of them.)

1. How can I disable all Gnome keyboard shortcuts?
2. Is there any app to map Gnome keyboard shortcuts to super key (or perfectly map to Windows equivalent keys)?
3. Essentially, why do Linux developers not use the super-key as an modifier key for OS-wide actions?

Comment: You should specify which version of Ubuntu. If Ubuntu 11.10, you should specify whether you are running Unity or GNOME (those are different things).

Comment: @gpoo I use Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution to your problem that might be more palatable for you is to change the keymap in PHPStorm to "Default for GNOME".  This will change the keyboard shortcut combinations so that conflicts with GNOME are removed.  I believe PHPStorm installs with "Default for XWin" as the default keymap, which includes shortcuts keys like Alt+F8 and Alt+F9  that conflict with GNOME window Window Management keyboard shortcuts.

Go to *File -> Settings* and select *Keymap* in *IDE Settings*.
Here's a screenshot with the relevant dropdown circled in PHPStorm keymap:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 11.04 ships by default Unity.  It also ships GNOME 2.32 (named 'GNOME Classic' when you want to start the session).

GNOME does not set Alt+Shift+Down.  So, if you are using GNOME, either:

1. You set the 'Compose' key by mistake in a different key.  Go to System-Preferences-Keyboard-Layout and choose the button 'options'.  The customizations are in bold.
2. You set it manually (or by mistake) in the global binding. Go to System-Preferences-Keyboard Shorcuts.

Also, GNOME ships metacity as window manager, but Ubuntu ships compiz by default.  So, to disable compiz:

1. Go to System-Preference-Appearance-Visual effects and set it to None. The keybinding should change.

However, I think you are running Unity (with compiz). In this case you should:

1. [check a similar answer in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40991/how-do-i-turn-off-the-alt-shift-uparrow-keybinding-in-gnome)
2. Edit your question and change 'GNOME' by 'Unity'.

Comment: 1- Please consider shift+alt+up

2- I do not use Unity (I use classic interface).